# Use row content as separator in GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: sql, group-concat

In my GROUP_CONCAT function I want to use the row content as a separator.

My function looks like this:

```
SELECT
        s.ID,
        s.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(st.name SEPARATOR '<a href="config/posthandling.php?deletefile='||st.name||'"><img src="img/delete.png" width=25 alt="delete" /></a><br/>')
    FROM
        streams s
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT
            i.streamID,
            f.name
        FROM
            streamfileimpacts i
        JOIN
            files f
        ON
            f.ID = i.fileID) st
    ON
        st.streamID = s.ID
    GROUP BY
        s.ID
```

but I always get an mysql-error. Is this even possible or do I have another mistake?

BR
Kai

Comment: show your entire query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(
       st.name,
       '<a href="config/posthandling.php?deletefile=',
       st.name,
       '"><img src="img/delete.png" width=25 alt="delete" /></a><br/>'
    ) 
    SEPARATOR ''
)
```